# Is it possible to estimate the amount data that a Spark application processes?

Tags: apache-spark

Which information in the Spark event logs can be used to estimate the amount data processed by a Spark application?

When analyzing the event logs and specifically the `SparkListenerTaskEnd` event, which fields could be used?

For example, in the field `Task Info` there is a field called Accumulables containing a list with objects conveying information about for example `data size total (min, med, max)`, `internal.metrics.input.bytesRead` and `internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten`. However, it is not clear to me if this is accumulated data for the task, the stage or the entire application?

In addition, the `Task Metrics` (in the `SparkListenerTaskEnd` event) field also contains objects such as `Shuffle Read Metrics`, `Shuffle Write Metrics`, `Input Metrics`, `Output Metrics` that in turn contains fields `Shuffle Bytes Written`, `Bytes Read`, `Bytes Written`. I guess these are task specific, however, how should these fields be combined to estimate the amount data processed?

Finally, how should all `SparkListenerTaskEnd` events from the event logs be summarized to estimate the entire amount data processed by the spark application?